# Using a new line character in the ansible find module

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

Trying to add a valid python regex as a parameter for the patterns option in the find module, but it's not working.

```
 tasks:
- name: Obtain a list of auto* files in /etc
  find:
    path: /etc
    patterns: "^auto(_|\\.)([a-zA-Z]+\n)"
    use_regex: yes
  register: etc_auto_files
```

The problem appears to be with the "\n", I have tried multiple backslashes, single quotes, and square brackets, but haven't been able to get it working.

I am running ansible 2.3.2.0.

Comment: You could try posting some code and examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try (not tested)

```
patterns: "^auto(_|\\.)([a-zA-Z]+{{'\n'}})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The pattern was meant to match filenames that are as follows:

```
/etc/auto_(one or more letters, end of filename) 
/etc/auto.(one or more letters, end of filename)
```

The following filenames are examples that would match the pattern:

```
/etc/auto.master or /etc/auto_master
```

The following filenames are examples that would not match the pattern:

```
/etc/old.auto.master
/etc/old.auto_master
/etc/auto.master.20180101
/etc/auto_master.20180101
```

The ansible pattern that ended up working:

```
"^auto(_|\\.)([a-zA-Z]+)$"
```

Here is how the pattern was successfully used in a find task:

```
- name: Obtain a list of auto* files in /etc
  find:
    path: /etc
    patterns:
      - "^auto(_|\\.)([a-zA-Z]+)$"
      - "^fstab$"
      - "^vfstab$"
    use_regex: yes
  register: etc_auto_files
```

Thanks to those who commented and attempted to answer this question.